# Changing a flash file

Tags: flash

I am trying to develop a way to change a flash file displayed on the screen to another file by clicking a button. I have been able to do this with jpg images, but I can't get it to work with flash files. Can anyone help? I would greatly appreciate it.
Below are two html's: the first one changes jpg images and it works, the second one I constructed to be similar to do the same with flash files but it does not work.

//Html 1. This changes Image 1 to Image 2 on click. It works

function changeSrc()
{
document.getElementById("myImage").src="Image 2.jpg";
}

//Html 2. This is intended to change Flash 1 to Flash 2 on click. It does not work

function changeSrc()
{
document.getElementById("myImage").src="Flash 2.swf";
}

Answer (score 1):

here you have an example of changing the flash embedded im js:

```
function setFlashSrc(newSrc)
    {
          var flash='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="210" HEIGHT="210">';
          flash+='<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="'+newSrc+'"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>';
          flash+='<EMBED SRC="'+newSrc+'" QUALITY=high PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" ';
          flash+='TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" WIDTH="210" HEIGHT="210">';
          flash+='</EMBED>';
          flash+='</OBJECT>';
          document.getElementById("urgeo").innerHTML=flash;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the name property of the embed or object tag to grab a reference to your embedded flash files. Using the id will not work.

But there is an easier way of doing this. if you use [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to embed your swfs, this can be as simple as one javascript call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = false;
var params = {
  menu: "false",
  flashvars: "name1=hello&name2=world&name3=foobar"
};
var attributes = {
  id: "myDynamicContent",
  name: "myDynamicContent"
};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```